# How replace and remove table row value by jquery

Tags: html, jquery

Hello friend I have table as follows:

```
<tbody class="sellbook">
    <tr class="foobar-26">
        <td>price</td>
        <td>amount</td>
        <td>total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foobar-27">
        <td>price</td>
        <td>amount</td>
        <td>total</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="foobar-28">
        <td>price</td>
        <td>amount</td>
        <td>total</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need to update data in the table row by mentioning its table row class name and need to remove also,
condition is as follows:

if value is zero , remove table row `foo25` , else replace with new `<td>`

```
var newtr = "<td>" + e.message.price + "</td>" + "<td>" + e.message.amount + "</td>" + "<td>" + e.message.total + "</td>";

let trclass = "foobar-" + e.message.id + "";

if (e.message.amount == 0) {
    $(".trclass").remove();
} else {
    $(".trclass").html(newtr);
}
```

but nothing happens with this code, what is wrong with the code?
can someone help me?

Comment: Typo?  `$('.trclass')` - You have no classes called "trclass".  Did you mean: `$('.' + trclass)` ?

Comment: because i make a class name by using database id value ```"foobar-"+e.message.id+""``` .should use variable name as class , need to call ```$('.'+trclass)``` ?

Comment: Which is why you'd want to use that *value* in your string, not just the name of the variable as a literal string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't how you use a variable in a string:

```
'.trclass'
```

That's just a literal string.  You can concatenate your value to a string:

```
'.' + trclass
```

or use the value in a template literal:

```
`.${trclass}`
```